# Trigger to create sum all the opportunities under the account

Tags: trigger

I am not able to sum all the opportunities under the account ? 
How will I do that?

What I have to use in this to run the trigger?
Is it possible to create because opp. is child and account is parent ?

```
trigger sumAllopptyAmtAccount on Account(before insert) {
    Set < ID > AccID = New Set < ID > ();
    if (Trigger.isInsert)
        for (Account oppAc: trigger.New) {
            AccID.add(oppAc.AccountID);
        }
    List < Account > acc = [select id, SumAll_Opprty__c from Account where id in: a.AccID];
    List < Opportunity > opp = [selece id from Opportunity where AccountID in: a.AccID];
    for (Account a: acc) {
        a.SumAll_Opprty__c = con.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to display  by using of triggers, Is it possible to do?

Comment: And im saying you don't need to use a trigger to do this, a roll up will work for you

Comment: Yes Roll up summary is working, but i m trying to create by using of trigger code.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem, or are you just curious?  This sounds like a http://xyproblem.info/, but short answer yes you can .. I have no idea why would you want to though

Comment: From the business point of the view there is limitation of Roll up field summary.If opportunity is more than the limit then we required trigger code.

Comment: Ok, i am sending my code, what i have done?

Comment: Does that code work?  What are you going to do about your backlog of already inserted Accounts?

Comment: Trigger even t should be `after insert` trigger because in `before insert` you don't have `ID` of the `Account`;

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a roll-up
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en

Comment: When i create 3 oppty on same account then its sum all oppty in account.But below code is not working properly

Comment: trigger sumAllopptyAmtAccount on Account (before insert) {Set<ID> AccID = New Set<ID>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert)
        for(Account oppAc : trigger.New){
            AccID.add(oppAc.AccountID);
        }
List<Account> acc=[select id,SumAll_Opprty__c from Account where id in:a.AccID];
    List<Opportunity> opp=[selece id from Opportunity where AccountID in: a.AccID];
    for(Account a: acc){
        a.SumAll_Opprty__c =con.size();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
trigger oppInAccount on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {
    Integer i ;
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    Set<Id> set1 = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Integer> map1 = new Map<Id,Integer>();
    for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.new){
            if(set1.contains(opp.AccountId) && map1.get(opp.AccountId) !=null){
                i = map1.get(opp.AccountId);
                i++;
                map1.put(opp.AccountId,i);
            }
            else{
                 i = 1;
            set1.add(opp.AccountId);
            map1.put(opp.AccountId,i);
            }
    }   
    accList =[SELECT noOfOpportunity__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :set1];
    for(Account ac:accList){
        ac.noOfOpportunity__c =map1.get(ac.Id);
    }
    update accList;
  }
```

[image: Result1]
[image: Result]
Regards,

Ajay

Comment: N.B. this doesn't cater to delete use case

Answer (score 0):

CHeck out this code :

```
trigger SumOfOpportunities on Opportunity (after insert,after update) 
{
Set<Id> accIdSet = new Set<Id>(); 
List<opportunity> oppList = new List<opportunity>();
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
for(opportunity o : trigger.new)
{
    accIdSet.add(o.accountId);
}

map<Id,Account> mapAcc = new map<Id,Account>([Select id, name, (Select id, amount From Opportunities) From Account Where Id IN : accIdSet]);

for(Account a : mapAcc.values())
{
    Decimal sum = 0;
    Account acc = mapAcc.get(a.id);
    for(Opportunity op: acc.opportunities)
    {
        sum = sum + (op.amount!= null?op.amount:0);
    }
    acc.Oppo_SUm__c = sum;
    accList.add(acc);
}
update accList;
}
```

Comment: @user28787 have you tried this code ???